# TFLearn training getting slower with time

Tags: python, tensorflow, tflearn

I am using [this](https://github.com/MrGrimod/gta_self_driving/blob/master/model/cnn_model.py) CNN Model to train my Nework.
First i initialized it in my [train_model.py](https://github.com/MrGrimod/gta_self_driving/blob/master/train_model.py):

```
 model = cnn_model.googlenet(WIDTH, HEIGHT, 3, LR, output=8, model_name=MODEL_NAME)
```

then I define the training loop and inside of that, I placed the *model.fit* function:

```
model.fit({'input': batch_x}, {'targets': batch_y}, n_epoch=1, snapshot_step=2510, show_metric=True, run_id=MODEL_NAME)
```

for some reason the network slows down with time and after round about 13 hours tf throws an exception: *Memory error*

Comment: Is `Memory error` the whole error message? Have you tried with less data?

Comment: I didn't post the full except. because it is the standard error for memory. overflow.